# Make IE 9 work in standard mode without Doctype

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, doctype

I hope someone here can help me. I know that in IE 9, there is quirks mode and standard mode, if I do not define a doctype such as :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

as the VERY FIRST line of my html, the browser will go into quirks mode.

Here is the problem, I'm writing something in HTML, which will then be embedded into another site(which I've checked, doesn't have doctype declaration, the site belongs to my school so I have no way of changing it).

So in the end it will be something like this

```
<html> .... </html> //the original website code
<!DOCTYPE html>//my doctype declaration
<html>... </html> //my html code
```

As you can see, my DOCTYPE becomes useless.

And no, there is no way I can change the original html code nor can I force it to use iframe or anything else that might help me.

So my question is, is there anyone to force IE 9 to run in standard mode without DOCTYPE?

I have tried:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> //putting page in xhtml

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />//forcing it like this
```

none of them worked for me.

Any ideas ?

Really appreciate any help at all at this point.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:UPDATE :

Hi Everyone, Thanks for the help. I know that it is horrible practice to have < html > ... < html > ... < /html > ... < /html >. However this is a limitation of my project and I have no control over it. Also, I can only manipulate the inner < html >..< /html >.

I searched around, and it seems like there is no "awesome" solution, as someone suggested, it might be possible to use Javascript to force IE 9 to run in standard mode, however that is not ideal for my project.

What I ended up doing was stripping my html page of css (so that it doesn't matter if the browser runs in standard mode or not), instead, I added in-line styling (very basic ones) throughout the HTML as a painful work-around.

It seems like this is a corner-case that IE 9 didn't anticipate, this problem doesn't exist in Chrome, Firefox, IE 8, as I have tested.

Anyways, Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: also please note that you must not have in a single html document a construction like you mentionied: `<html>...</html><html>...</html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why without `<!DOCTYPE>`? It is the worst idea to choose.

The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML document, before the `<html>` tag. The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is not an HTML tag. It is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

**A DOCTYPE (short for “document type declaration”) informs the validator which version of (X)HTML you’re using, and must appear at the very top of every web page. DOCTYPEs are a key component of compliant web pages: your markup and CSS won’t validate without them.**

Good reads:

1. [Fix Your Site With the Right DOCTYPE!](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/)
2. [Recommended Doctype Declarations to use in your Web document.](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in the question, I cannot choose what the first line in the final html (the original html + my html) is. so I can't put doctype in the first line, even though I definitely want to do that. Is there a work around such that doctype declaration doesn't have to be the first line ?

Comment: @JJackJi doctype doesn't need to on first since if you use languages like php you have to start session at the very first line of the page or header you need to declare the docktype before the html tag

Comment: Hi I think for IE 9, it has to be the first line,  otherwise it will go into quirks mode which messes up css.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. If you think the answer is “you cannot”, you should say that, with references if possible. The chat about formal requirements and validation is not relevant at all, and it is partly incorrect (the doctype *only* triggers standards/almost standards/quirks mode, it does not “inform about HTML version”).

Answer (score 0):

You can choose standards mode, or quirks mode, only at the start of the content of the page.  (And maybe using a meta tag near the start, too, or using an HTTP header, but I'm not an IE expert to be sure of either.  And I think some of this changed in IE9 or maybe IE10, so there's a legacy-browser version concern to either.)  And once it's been chosen, you can't "switch" to another mode partway through the page, then back at some later point.

Which means that if your content is going to be inserted midway in the page, and you can't control or affect the outer parts, you're going to have to live with your content being rendered using quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` tag as early as possible in your code. It must appear after the `<!doctype ...>` declaration, after the `<html>` tag, and after the `<head>` tag if present, but it should then appear before any other tag.

For example, if there is just `<style></style>` (a `style` element with empty content) before it, IE 9 goes to Quirks Mode. Apparently, IE wants to decide on the mode before working on constructs that may be affected by the mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to embrace quirks mode, sorry.

It's evil, but in theory, you can do something like this below.

```
<html>
<title>Bad School Code - No DOCTYPE</title>
<!-- embedded code  -->
<script type="text/html"><!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>My Properly DOCTYPE'd Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>lorem ipsum solor sit amet</p>
    <script>
      document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(((document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat')?'Standards': 'Quirks')+' mode.'));
    <\/script>
  </body>
 </html>
</script>
<script>
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
  var embedded = scripts[scripts.length - 2];
  var text = (embedded.firstChild ? embedded.firstChild.nodeValue : embedded.innerHTML).replace('\\/', '/');
  window.onload = function() {
    document.write(text);
  }
</script> 
<!-- end embedded code  -->
</html>
```

The document.write blows away the container page and replaces it with your page, which you put inside the `<script type="text/html">` block. You will need to replace `</script>` with `<\/script>` in your page throughout to stop the `<script type="text/html">` block being ended prematurely but otherwise there shouldn't be any changes necessary.

Note that in the example above, the html left remaining after document.write has run is valid HTML5, and that the entire page will, if you tell the validator to validate it as HTML5, also pass validation.

However, the container code provided by your school is presumably doing something important and the code above would destroy that, so you'd need to rebuild it in your code. Before using this, GET PERMISSION. Odds are, if your school is incapable of providing you with a standards mode page to begin with, and requires you to put your page inside theirs, they're not going to approve of (or even understand) trickery like this.